# html2pdf special characters not rendered

Tags: unicode, encoding, fonts, html2pdf

I am using [html2pdf](https://github.com/iafan/html2pdf) library for genarating pdf with bookmarked index. By default it seems to work well for English content but i need to generate content that includes English & Arabic text.  The "aefurat" font seems to work relatively good, except some special characters (’, ‘, “, ”, ...) that are rendered as boxes ([]).

The code I used is,

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../html2pdf.class.php');
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', 0);
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('aefurat');      
$html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output('bookmark.pdf');
```

A Sample content that includes arabic and special chararacters is,

> ’This is Arabic’ "العربية" Example With TCPDF... some text here some
>   text here some “text here”.

Wondering if I need to use some other font or alter some configurations. Kindly advice me.